# Compare lines within a file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk

**input.txt file**

```
12345678,Manoj,23,Developer
12345678,Manoj,34,Developer
12345678,Manoj,67,Developer
12345679,Vijay,12,Tester
12345679,Vijay,98,Tester
12345676,Samrat,100,Manager
12345676,Samrat,25,Manager
12345676,Samrat,28,Manager
```

**Desired output file**

```
12345678,Manoj,23,Developer,0
12345678,Manoj,34,Developer,1
12345678,Manoj,67,Developer,2
12345679,Vijay,12,Tester,0
12345679,Vijay,98,Tester,1
12345676,Samrat,100,Manager,0
12345676,Samrat,25,Manager,1
12345676,Samrat,28,Manager,2
```

**Explanation**

Here the first value i.e `12345678` in the first 3 lines of my input file are the same so append the first 3 lines with ,`0 ,1 and ,2` respectively. And similarly to the following lines.

How it can be done in Shell Script.

**Edit in Desired Output**

Is is also possible to change the Desired Output number format to the following for the output?

```
12345678,Manoj,23,Developer,0000000
12345678,Manoj,34,Developer,0000001
12345678,Manoj,67,Developer,0000002
12345679,Vijay,12,Tester,0000000
12345679,Vijay,98,Tester,0000001
12345676,Samrat,100,Manager,0000000
12345676,Samrat,25,Manager,0000001
12345676,Samrat,28,Manager,0000002
```

**New:**
Is it possible to start the numbering from 0000019. Is there anyother option to initialize a variable like a=5, a=19, a=39 from where i can increment afterwards.

```
12345678,Manoj,23,Developer,0000019
12345678,Manoj,34,Developer,0000020
12345678,Manoj,67,Developer,0000021
12345679,Vijay,12,Tester,0000019
12345679,Vijay,98,Tester,0000020
12345676,Samrat,100,Manager,0000019
12345676,Samrat,25,Manager,0000020
12345676,Samrat,28,Manager,0000021
```

Comment: Do NOT change the contents of your question after an answer or comments have been provided. That makes all answers and comments before your edit no longer valid. Instead EDIT your question and **ADD** any additions to the bottom of your question. That way the answers and comments will remain valid. (you get one freebie for not knowing, but add next time `:)`

Comment: Noted @DavidC.Rankin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to fix my former self-unknown line-ending [error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55064816/5403468).

Use this, will work on both `\r\n` and `\n` line endings, output will end in `\n`:

```
awk -F, 'sub(/\r$/,"") ($(NF+1)=sprintf("%07d",a[$2]++))' OFS=, input.txt
```

Output:

```
12345678,Manoj,23,Developer,0000000
12345678,Manoj,34,Developer,0000001
12345678,Manoj,67,Developer,0000002
12345679,Vijay,12,Tester,0000000
12345679,Vijay,98,Tester,0000001
12345676,Samrat,100,Manager,0000000
12345676,Samrat,25,Manager,0000001
12345676,Samrat,28,Manager,0000002
```

I wrote like that is for conciseness, it's functionally equals to:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{sub(/\r$/,"");$(NF+1)=sprintf("%07d",a[$2]++)}1' input.txt
```

If you have `ruby` installed:

```
ruby -aF, -pe 'BEGIN{a=Hash.new(-1)};sub(/\r?$/, "," + "%07d" % a[$F[1]]+=1)' input.txt
```

Same output.

Btw, if you want it starts with 19, you can use this (add `19+` to the value):

```
awk 'sub(/\r$/,"") ($(NF+1)=sprintf("%07d",19+a[$2]++))' FS=, OFS=, input.txt
```

Or this(initialize with 18):

```
ruby -aF, -pe 'BEGIN{a=Hash.new(18)};sub(/\r?$/, "," + "%07d" % a[$F[1]]+=1)' input.txt
```

These all used `$2` (column 2) as the keys, since in your samples `$1` and `$2` are related, so use either one would work.

Answer (score 7):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";RS="\r?\n"}{print $0,a[$1]++}' file
```

Output:

```
12345678,Manoj,23,Developer,0
12345678,Manoj,34,Developer,1
12345678,Manoj,67,Developer,2
12345679,Vijay,12,Tester,0
12345679,Vijay,98,Tester,1
12345676,Samrat,100,Manager,0
12345676,Samrat,25,Manager,1
12345676,Samrat,28,Manager,2
```

**Edit**:

As the requirements changed and a lot of commenting took place, here is the final version (revision one as the requirements were different in comments and the OP, knocking on wood):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{sub(/\r$/,"");printf "%s,%07d" ORS,$0,a[$1]++}' file
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { 
    FS=","
    # ORS="\r\n"                     # uncomment if Windows line-endings are desired
}      
{
    sub(/\r$/,"")                    # remove Windows line-endings (ie. \r from \r\n)
    printf "%s,%07d" ORS,$0,a[$1]++  # output zeropadded running count on $1
}' file
```

Tested with gawk, mawk, busybox awk and the original-awk (awk version 20121220). Oh, and recycled my Solaris box 5 years ago. ;D

Comment: ,0345678,Manoj,002,Developer
,1345678,Manoj,002,Developer
,2345678,Manoj,002,Developer. The values are appended in the begining. i need the values to be appended at the end.

Comment: It is. You probably have Windows line-endings in the file (`\r\n)`. Fixed with `RS="\r?\n"`.

Comment: 12345678,Manoj,23,Developer,0000000
12345678,Manoj,34,Developer,0000001
12345678,Manoj,67,Developer,0000002. Is this modification possible.

Comment: `{printf "%s,%07d\n",$0,a[$1]++}` (well done @JamesBrown)

Comment: 12345678,Manoj,23,Developer,0000000
12345678,Manoj,34,Developer,0000001
12345678,Manoj,67,Developer,0000002
12345679,Vijay,12,Tester,0000003
12345679,Vijay,98,Tester,0000004
12345676,Samrat,100,Manager,0000005
12345676,Samrat,25,Manager,0000006
12345676,Samrat,28,Manager,0000007. Is this modification possible without comparing the first values in all lines

Comment: {printf "%s,%07d\n",$0,a++}

Comment: @Manoj Just a running number after the record? Sure, replace the `print` with `printf "%s,%08d\n",$0,NR`.

Comment: See, you can do it. Waiting for you to start answering these questions with us!

Comment: I will do sure... James

Comment: A couple of comments here: (1) The usage of `RS="\r?\n"` is not POSIX and this will only work on a few versions of awk (mainly gawk). (2) Most likely the dos-file should become a dos-file again, currently, the line-endings will be only "\n". You might want to use `printf` and `RT` instead of `print` which appends the default`ORS` (3) There is no need to set `FS`. (`awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r?\n"}{printf "%s,%0.7d" RT; $0,a[$1]++}' file`)

Comment: @JamesBrown I know you know most of this, I just wrote it as a general comment for people who read your answer.

Comment: Tested succesfully with gawk, mawk and busybox awk, unsuccesfully with the "original awk" that ships with Debian.

Comment: @JamesBrown good to know that these 3 cases work. Solaris awk fails. Posix only expects a single character as `RS` and not a `BRE`.

Comment: What is the way to start the numbering from 00000001 instead 00000000

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{sub(/\r$/,"");printf "%s,%07d" ORS,$0,++a[$1]}' file` ie. `++a[$1]` instead of `a[$1]++`.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for swift reply. But the starting number varies from 00000001, 00000020, 00000039. Is there anyother option to initialize a variable like a=1, a=20, a=39 from where i can increment afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.(without editing line simply print it by addiotnal array's count value)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {printf("%s,%07d\n",$0,count[$2]++)}' Input_file
```

Comment: @Manoj, could you please do let me know reason for removing my answer as correct one here?

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl

```
$ cat manoj.txt
12345678,Manoj,23,Developer
12345678,Manoj,34,Developer
12345678,Manoj,67,Developer
12345679,Vijay,12,Tester
12345679,Vijay,98,Tester
12345676,Samrat,100,Manager
12345676,Samrat,25,Manager
12345676,Samrat,28,Manager
$ perl -F, -lane ' $F[$#F]=~s/\r//g; $F[$#F+1]=sprintf("%07d",$kv{$F[0]}++);$,=",";  print @F ' manoj.txt
12345678,Manoj,23,Developer,0000000
12345678,Manoj,34,Developer,0000001
12345678,Manoj,67,Developer,0000002
12345679,Vijay,12,Tester,0000000
12345679,Vijay,98,Tester,0000001
12345676,Samrat,100,Manager,0000000
12345676,Samrat,25,Manager,0000001
12345676,Samrat,28,Manager,0000002
$
```

Comment: can you explain this? i can't known `$kv` variable , thank you